# Visual C#, process grows until I get memory errors relating to a UserControl using a loop to draw graphics

Tags: c#

Using Visual C# 2008 Exp Edition, I've noticed that with my project loaded the process is consuming ~70,000K of memory. After a few hours this builds up to about ~500,000K.

At this point a `UserControl` containing a `PictureBox` (within a `Panel`) shows a memory error in Visual C# Express. The picture box contains a bitmap and grid of rectangles, drawn with `System.Drawing.Graphics`.

Here's the code:

This segement occurs just once when the `UserControl` is initialised.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(a, b);
Graphics g = null;
g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.SteelBlue, 0, 0, c, d);

//Paint Rows & Columns
for (int x = 0; x <= e - 1; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= f - 1; y++)
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, g, h, i);
    }
}
//Release Resources
g.Dispose();
//Add bitmap with grid to BG
ScorePictureBox.Image = myBitmap;
```

This piece of code is quite frequent:

```
for (int EventIndex = 0; EventIndex <= MidiNoteDownArray.Length - 1; EventIndex++)
{
    //Paint notes to grid

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, j, k, l, m);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Purple, o, p, q, r);
}
e.Dispose();
```

Am I not releasing resources properly? How can I do this correctly?rrect

Comment: Or all of the error message...

Comment: You'd be better off creating a new post for new questions.  Completely changing a question removes all context for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the bitmaps you're creating - when you replace the image on your `ScorePictureBox`, you need to dispose of the old one, i.e:

```
var oldImage = ScorePictureBox.Image;
//Add bitmap with grid to BG
ScorePictureBox.Image = myBitmap;
// Dispose of previous score image if necessary
if (oldImage != null) oldImage.Dispose();
```

Note the double-handling - it's generally best not to dispose of a GDI+ object while other items are still referencing them.

On a general syntactic note, you'd probably be better off with `using` statements instead of explicit calls to `Dispose()`, i.e.:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your project. Maybe you are missing a reference.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: the class is simple, I cannot create an instance. how do i referance it?

Comment: In Visual Studio there's an item under each project in solution explorer where you can define references. I think you can just right click on project and do Add Reference. I am on a Mac at the moment. Will get my pc and look.

Comment: Is the class you want in a different source file, different assembly, different project? I suggested the reference because it's a common reason. May not be your reason.